# XML error when not using XML in unity [Unity]

Tags: visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Whenever I start up my unity project I get a weird XML error. I haven't found any info online and it docent send me anywhere when I click on it. I cant think of anything that could have caused this as I never use any form of XML. The only XML thing that I think I use is stuff like this:

```
    /// Moves object with x and y velocity
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="moveAmount">Vecotr2 velocity to move object by</param>
    /// <param name="standingOnPlatform">Is object standing on a platform</param>
    public void Move(Vector2 moveAmount, bool standingOnPlatform)
    {
```

Here is the error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document (8, 2). ---> System.Xml.XmlException: Name cannot begin with the '<' character, hexadecimal value 0x3C. Line 8, position 2.
  at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw (System.Exception e) [0x00027] in <0f9699188f0c414ea6fb5557f5c16d15>:0 
  at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw (System.String res, System.String[] args) [0x00029] in <0f9699188f0c414ea6fb5557f5c16d15>:0 
  at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw (System.Int32 pos, System.String res, System.String[] args) [0x0000c] in <0f9699188f0c414ea6fb5557f5c16d15>:0 
  at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseQName (System.Boolean isQName, System.Int32 startOffset, System.Int32& colonPos) [0x00088] in <0f9699188f0c414ea6fb5557f5c16d15>:0 
  at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseQName (System.Int32& colonPos) [0x00000] in <0f9699188f0c414ea6fb5557f5c16d15>:0 
  at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElement () [0x000b2] in <0f9699188f0c414ea6fb5557f5c16d15>:0 
  at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent () [0x0016f] in <0f9699188f0c414ea6fb5557f5c16d15>:0 
  at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read () [0x00085] in <0f9699188f0c414ea6fb5557f5c16d15>:0 
  at System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read () [0x00000] in <0f9699188f0c414ea6fb5557f5c16d15>:0 
  at System.Xml.XmlReader.ReadElementString () [0x0008a] in <0f9699188f0c414ea6fb5557f5c16d15>:0 
  at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderERPSettings.Read2_ERPSettings (System.Boolean isNullable, System.Boolean checkType) [0x002c8] in <57c2328f92824fafb5685e18b4b64ee8>:0 
  at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderERPSettings.Read3_ERPSettings () [0x00050] in <57c2328f92824fafb5685e18b4b64ee8>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00032] in <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize (System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader, System.String encodingStyle, System.Xml.Serialization.XmlDeserializationEvents events) [0x0011b] in <0f9699188f0c414ea6fb5557f5c16d15>:0 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize (System.Xml.XmlReader xmlReader, System.String encodingStyle) [0x00000] in <0f9699188f0c414ea6fb5557f5c16d15>:0 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize (System.IO.Stream stream) [0x0001c] in <0f9699188f0c414ea6fb5557f5c16d15>:0 
  at ERP.ERPSettings.GetSettings () [0x00027] in C:\Users\Billy1301\Documents\Programming\Unity Games\Roguelike-Master\Assets\ERP\Editor\ERPSettings.cs:45 
  at ERP.ERP..cctor () [0x00032] in C:\Users\Billy1301\Documents\Programming\Unity Games\Roguelike-Master\Assets\ERP\Editor\ERP.cs:40 
UnityEditor.EditorAssemblies:ProcessInitializeOnLoadAttributes (System.Type[])
```

Any help would be amazing.

Comment: could be an error with the comments, try using `/*....*/` also share your code for reference with line-numberings. Seems to be an error in line 8

Comment: I have deleted all of the comments and it still gives me the error. My project has like 20 files so I only showed what I thought was relevant. What specifically would you like to see.

Comment: Roguelike-Master\Assets\ERP\Editor\ERP.cs:40  Roguelike-Master\Assets\ERP\Editor\ERPSettings.cs:45

Comment: ERP.cs : 40
`
38 static ERP()
39         {
40             ERPSettings.GetSettings();
41             DelayStart();
42         }
`

Comment: ERPSettings.cs:45

39 public static void GetSettings()
40         {
41             if (File.Exists(path))
42             {
43                 XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ERPSettings));
44                 FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
45                 ERPSettings settings = serializer.Deserialize(stream) as ERPSettings;
46                 ApplySettings(settings);
47                 stream.Close();
48            }
49         }

Comment: sorry about the formatting

Comment: ERP.cs:40 = ERPSettings.GetSettings();

Comment: ERPSettings.cs:45 = ERPSettings settings = serializer.Deserialize(stream) as ERPSettings;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution:
I was using a Discord Presence plugin (Displays your current Unity project as your discord status). I found that this was causing the problem and I removed it and the error is gone.